# Python module ftplib FTP_TLS - Error 530

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm using  Python 2.7 on ubuntu 11.10 distribution.

I have a problem with ftplib module and FTP_TLS connection.
On my ftp server there is vsftp

When try a connection I receive this error:

**ftplib.error_perm: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.**

This is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp =  FTP_TLS( '192.168.1.5' )
ftp.login( 'user' , 'password') 
ftp.close()
```

Anyway if I use the simple FTP connection, ftp =  FTP('192.168.1.5') , it works!

But I need FTP_TLS connection. I tried also to insert param ftp.auth() and ftp.prot_p() but nothing happens.

Answer (score 10):

The `FTP_TLS` class doesn't seem to handle logins very well right now. Unfortunately, you have to explicitly send those commands to the server yourself.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

# Do *not* specify the user and password in the FTP_TLS constructor arguments.
# Doing so will cause ftplib to try to login, resulting in the 530 error.
ftp = FTP_TLS('ftp.somewhere.com')
ftp.sendcmd('USER myusername') # '331 Please specify the password.'
ftp.sendcmd('PASS mypassword') # '230 Login successful.'
```

Comment: It's still the case :C

Comment: FTP_TLS works correctly now,  you can pass the username and password in the constructor:

client = FTP_TLS(host="hostnamegoeshere", user="usernamegoeshere", passwd="pwgoeshere")

Answer (score 0):

Try [TLS Lite](http://trevp.net/tlslite/) or [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) both are FTP/TLS client and server.

Comment: I prefer m2crypto, but the choice is yours:)